# How can I combine any emoji with another using UTF-8 code and Python

Tags: javascript, python, unicode, utf-8, special-characters

I wanna know how can I create the Verification tick (like on Instagram) by combining two emojis with Javascript or Python.

I tried to do it by combining ✓ with  but I failed, then I got deeper so I combined ☑ with  adding a Zero-Width Joiner and I failed.

So please if someone can create a Verification tick like on facebook or tiktok please paste it ;)

Comment: The verification icon is not a Unicode character. What makes you think it is?

Comment: Isn't the verification icon just a custom graphic? If it could be reproduced with Unicode then it could be faked. The whole point is that it's something that can't be faked or reproduced. Also I don't think you really want Python or JavaScript code to do this, but just want the results. You can't circumvent the rules of this site like that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SebastianSimon why do you think that `✓` (U+2713,  *Check Mark*)  is not a Unicode character?

Comment: @JosefZ U+2713 is not the Twitter verification mark.

Comment: Instagram is using image sprites, not emojis, for their verification mark. If you want to use a tick or checkbox emoji styled like a verification mark, you'd need to use the codepoint followed by VS16, and then create or modify a font with the emoji styled the way you want.